# how to load font-awesome icon inside vlaue of input field

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to load a font-awesome icon inside a vlue of an input field but do not succeed in it:

Code below gives me literally:`<i class="fas fa-times"></i>`

```
<input type="submit" class="sfmdelete"  name="delete" value="<i class='fas fa-times'></i>" />
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve--
Add the following to your css.
You can use font-awesome as regular font too.

```
input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" class="search" value="&#xf002;" />
```

Link to the FontAwesome ascii code (cheatsheet): [this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet)

Comment: I agree. this works fine. Thnx